# Connecting to Azure SQL DB via JTDS on an Android device

Tags: java, android, jdbc, azure, jtds

I'm using JTDS 1.2.7 to connect my Android app to a Windows Azure SQL Server.

Source code:

```
String connectionString = 
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;database=demo;" +
"user=test@SERVER;password=PASSWORD;ssl=require";
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
res=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

When I try to connect to the database I get the 
java.lang.NoClassDefError: com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext
exception.
I tried to add jsse.jar to my build path, but the app just shuts down instead of making connection.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a an issue when you use JTDS driver with JDK 1.6+ - http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7105007.. you will need to set JVM property -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false to be able to connect with JTDS driver but this is NOT recommended.

Recommended driver to connect to SQL Azure using Java for now is the Microsoft JDBC driver and here are some details on how to use it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715284.aspx

Comment: FYI, -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false appears to still be required for Java 7 and 8 -- it solved my connection issue on OpenJDK 1.7.0_55